# Из за чего диспетчер aiogram не может зарегистрировать хендлеры?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Почему-то aiogram не ловит сообщения, все хендлеры, которые я пытаюсь зарегистрировать не работают

Однако если раскомментировать к примеру пятую строку, то хендлер работает.С чем это может быть связано?До этого писал ботов, все было нормально, начал проект с нуля и тут такая проблема

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

#@dp.message_handler(commands=['start','help'])
async def commands_start(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Hello')
    await message.delete()


def register_handlers_client(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(commands_start, commands=['start','help'])
```

Comment: а как он их должен ловить, если вы их комментируете?

Comment: В последних двух строчках я же зарегистрировал хендлер

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вы не вызываете функцию `register_handlers_client` при запуске. Это должно решить проблему:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register_handlers_client(dp)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Вот минимальный работоспособный код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

TOKEN = 'ТВОЙ ТОКЕН'

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def commands_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello')
    await message.delete()


def register_handlers_client(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(commands_start, commands=['start', 'help'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register_handlers_client(dp)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я это делаю...

Если добавить костыль, в виде print('ok') в теле функции register_handlers_client, то в консоле выведется ok

Другими словами, функция вызывается...
`from handlers import client, admin, other

client.register_handlers_client(dp)


executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True, on_startup = on_startup)`

Comment: проверьте, я добавил в ответ полностью рабочий вариант

Comment: Перепроверял много раз, просто start_poling и вызов функции register_handlers_client(dp) находится у меня в другом файле